# Link-only answer, flagged, deleted, then undeleted

Tags: support, flags, not-an-answer, link-only-answers

In the span of about 15 minutes, I flagged [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45136083/1226963) as NAA, the user deleted the answer (for no apparent reason at that point), and then the user undeleted the answer.

So now my flag shows as "helpful" and I can't flag it again as NAA.

The entire answer is simply:

> Check out this link. It may helps you <a URL here>

How can this "answer" be flagged again as a NAA?

(And of course the answer has now been deleted via Meta effect).

Comment: If poster-initiated deletion/undeletion gets the answer out of the LQP queue, that's a hack that needs to be fixed. If the post is still in the LQP queue, I would assume that it will be deleted by reviewers after a bit.

Comment: [post timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45136083/timeline) shows that your flag, as well as [LQ review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/16731686), were "shaken off" by OP deletion-undeletion. Wonder if trick like that triggered automated mod flag (it usually does but this time user did it so fast that I am not sure that this happened). Looks like a [known bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/197964/165773)... and it becomes more and more annoying since more users learn about this way to abuse the system

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As gnat pointed out above, deletion of an answer by the owner automatically marks as helpful any "not an answer" or "very low quality" flags on that post. They then have the ability to undelete their self-deleted answer, and none of the flags will remain.

Users can also undelete answers of theirs deleted in review, but in those cases the system warns moderators via an automated system flag. We then review those and can delete them using one of our votes which cannot be overridden as easily.

Answerers deleting and undeleting posts to clear flags doesn't happen often, because they have no means of knowing that their post has been flagged. It's usually pure chance that causes this. Because of how rare this is, I'd recommend casting a custom flag and letting us know about it when you see it happen. I've deleted this one.

Comment: Thanks Brad. I knew that flags like this automatically appear as helpful when the offending answer is deleted. I just threw that in to be complete. I was more concerned with how to deal with this specific situation of the undelete and apparent removing from the review queue. As for your suggestion in the future, I don't think I could flag the answer again since I had already flagged the answer as NAA. And thanks for deleting the answer.

Comment: @rmaddy I believe you can always flag as "other" (or whatever current wording for "needs moderator input") irrespective if you've already flagged the post.

Answer (score 0):

What i know the system work like this, the flag marked helpful if the post is deleted, in this case the system mark your flag as helpful and can't return back again if the post is undeleted, and you can flag only one for each post so for that you can't flag it again.